# В чем причина ошибки - element.append is not a function?

Tags: javascript

```js
/*
пример навигации:

<article class="article wrap">
                  <section class="article-navigation">
                     <h3>Навигация по статье</h3>
                     <ul>
                        <li><a href="">AAA</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Получение</a></li>
                     </ul>
                  </section>
</article>
*/
let h2s = d.getElementsByTagName("h2");
let article = document.querySelector("main > article");
/*====================== строю DOM навигации =======================*/
function buildNavigation() {
  let articleNavigation = d.createElement("section").className = "article-navigation",
    articleNavigation__h3 = d.createElement("h3").textContent = "Навигация по статье",
    articleNavigation__ul = d.createElement("ul"),
    articleNavigation__li = d.createElement("li"),
    articleNavigation__navLinks = d.createElement("a");

  articleNavigation.prepend(articleNavigation__h3);
  //^^^ problem is here. append and appendChild methods don't work too
  articleNavigation.append(articleNavigation__ul);

  for (let i = 0; i < h2s.length; i++) {
    articleNavigation__navLinks.setAttribute("href", i);
    articleNavigation__navLinks.textContent = h2s[i].textContent
    articleNavigation__li.append(articleNavigation__navLinks);
    articleNavigation__ul.append(articleNavigation__li);
  }
  article.prepend(articleNavigation)
}
```

Comment: когда в процессе генерации то вставляете внутрь сгенерированного элемента методом innerHTML, после чего вставляете внутрь страницы сгенерированный элемент с текстом методом append

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Результатом присваивания в такой форме будет являться не тип `Node`, а `String`.

Операторы присваивания вычисляют значения справа налево и вычисленное значение передают в переменную.
Если ваш код разбить на два присваивания, то получится следующее

```
1. Вычислить первое присваивание
d.createElement("section").className = "article-navigation" // -> "article-navigation"
2. Вычислить второе присваивание
let articleNavigation = "article-navigation" // -> "article-navigation"
```

Таким образом у вас в `articleNavigation` хранится строка, у которой естественно нет искомого метода.

Сделайте себе (или разработчикам-коллегам) одолжение, и разбейте код на две логически законченные операции. Потом, возвращаясь к своему коду через неделю-другую, вам будет все понятно.

Кстати, со следующим присваиванием такая же история.

Answer (score 0):

Добавление класса для созданного элемента необходимо перенести ниже отдельной строкой. Иначе в левую часть записывается результат присвоения класса элементу, а не сам элемент.

```
let articleNavigation = d.createElement("section");
articleNavigation.className = "article-navigation";
```